# php two-dimensional array format converted to echarts format in laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a result set that is queried from a database.

```
    $promotions = array(
        array('goods_num' => 2, 'promotion_type' => 'General goods', 'date' => '2020-02-04',),
        array('goods_num' => 1, 'promotion_type' => 'Discount', 'date' => '2020-02-04',),
        array('goods_num' => 1, 'promotion_type' => 'Flash sale', 'date' => '2020-02-04',),
        
        array('goods_num' => 10, 'promotion_type' => 'Discount', 'date' => '2020-02-05',),
        array('goods_num' => 10, 'promotion_type' => 'General goods', 'date' => '2020-02-05',),
        array('goods_num' => 9, 'promotion_type' => 'Flash sale', 'date' => '2020-02-05',),

        array('goods_num' => 2, 'promotion_type' => 'Flash sale', 'date' => '2020-02-06',),
        array('goods_num' => 1, 'promotion_type' => 'General goods', 'date' => '2020-02-06',),
        array('goods_num' => 2, 'promotion_type' => 'General goods', 'date' => '2020-02-06',),

        array('goods_num' => 1, 'promotion_type' => 'General goods', 'date' => '2020-02-07',),
        array('goods_num' => 2, 'promotion_type' => 'Flash sale', 'date' => '2020-02-07',),
        array('goods_num' => 3, 'promotion_type' => 'Discount', 'date' => '2020-02-07',),
    );
```

And I want to show it as a chart. like this [demo](https://www.echartsjs.com/examples/en/editor.html?c=dataset-link&theme=light),I want to convert the above array into this format：

```
 array(
        0 => array(0 => 'date', 1 => '2020-02-04', 2 => '2020-02-05', 3 => '2020-02-06', 4 => '2020-02-07',),
        1 => array(0 => 'General goods', 1 => 2, 2 => 10, 3 => 3, 4 => 1,),
        2 => array(0 => 'Discount', 1 => 1, 2 => 10, 3 => 0, 4 => 3,),
        3 => array(0 => 'Flash sale', 1 => 1, 2 => 9, 3 => 2, 4 => 2,),
    );
```

The first line is the date of the x-axis,After that is the sum of the goods_num in the date of each promotion.

I tried using two foreach loops to handle it, but I couldn't get the result I wanted.
thank you all

Comment: where's the `foreach` you tried? include it as well, its missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array_column to get the dates then loop the array to build the goods_num.

```
$promotions = array(
        array('goods_num' => 2, 'promotion_type' => 'General goods', 'date' => '2020-02-04',),
        array('goods_num' => 1, 'promotion_type' => 'Discount', 'date' => '2020-02-04',),
        array('goods_num' => 1, 'promotion_type' => 'Flash sale', 'date' => '2020-02-04',),

        array('goods_num' => 10, 'promotion_type' => 'Discount', 'date' => '2020-02-05',),
        array('goods_num' => 10, 'promotion_type' => 'General goods', 'date' => '2020-02-05',),
        array('goods_num' => 9, 'promotion_type' => 'Flash sale', 'date' => '2020-02-05',),

        array('goods_num' => 2, 'promotion_type' => 'Flash sale', 'date' => '2020-02-06',),
        array('goods_num' => 1, 'promotion_type' => 'General goods', 'date' => '2020-02-06',),
        array('goods_num' => 2, 'promotion_type' => 'General goods', 'date' => '2020-02-06',),

        array('goods_num' => 1, 'promotion_type' => 'General goods', 'date' => '2020-02-07',),
        array('goods_num' => 2, 'promotion_type' => 'Flash sale', 'date' => '2020-02-07',),
        array('goods_num' => 3, 'promotion_type' => 'Discount', 'date' => '2020-02-07',),
    );

$dates = array_unique(array_column($promotions , "date"));
$new[] = array(array_merge(['date'], $dates));
// Now the array has all the dates done

foreach($promotions as $item){

// Make associative array and place values in the subarrays

    if(!isset($new[$item['promotion_type']])){
        $new[$item['promotion_type']][] = $item['promotion_type'];
    }
    $new[$item['promotion_type']][] =$item['goods_num'];
}

//Remove associative array
$new = array_values($new);
var_dump($new);
```

https://3v4l.org/GDNpP

Answer (score 2):

I solved it with laravel's collection：

```
 $dataSets = array_unique( array_column($promotions, 'date'));
    $promotionTypes = array_unique(array_column($promotions, 'promotion_type'));

    $promotionTypeOrders = $promotions->groupBy('promotion_type')->map(function ($item) {
        return $item->groupBy('date');
    });

    $promotionGroups = [];

    foreach ($dateSets as $dateSet) {
        foreach ($promotionTypes as $promotionType) {
            $promotionGroups[$promotionType][$dateSet] = isset($promotionTypeOrders[$promotionType][$dateSet]) ? $promotionTypeOrders[$promotionType][$dateSet]->sum('goods_num') : 0;
        }
    }
    $result = [];
    foreach ($promotionGroups as $promotionName => $promotionGroup) {
        $result[] = array_merge([$promotionName], array_values($promotionGroup));
    }

    array_unshift($dateSets, 'date');

    return array_merge([array_values($dateSets)], $result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is an example with raw PHP. But, you don`t have same count($keys) in your arrays, so:

```
# Create variables
$results  = [];
$date     = ['Date'];
$goods    = ['General goods'];
$sale     = ['Flash sale'];
$discount = ['Discount'];

# Fetch data
foreach ($promotions as $promo) {

    # Getting general goods values
    if (array_search('General goods', $promo)) {
        array_push($goods, $promo['goods_num']);
        array_push($date, $promo['date']);
    }

    # Getting flash sale values
    if (array_search('Flash sale', $promo)) {
        array_push($sale, $promo['goods_num']);
        array_push($date, $promo['date']);
    }

    # Getting discount values
    if (array_search('Discount', $promo)) {
        array_push($discount, $promo['goods_num']);
        array_push($date, $promo['date']);
    }
}

# Construct results
array_push($results, $date);
array_push($results, $goods);
array_push($results, $sale);
array_push($results, $discount);

# Clear ram
unset($date, $goods, $sale, $discount, $promo);

# Printing results
echo "<pre>";
print_r($results);
```

And the results:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Date
                [1] => 2020-02-04
                [2] => 2020-02-04
                [3] => 2020-02-04
                [4] => 2020-02-05
                [5] => 2020-02-05
                [6] => 2020-02-05
                [7] => 2020-02-06
                [8] => 2020-02-06
                [9] => 2020-02-06
                [10] => 2020-02-07
                [11] => 2020-02-07
                [12] => 2020-02-07
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => General goods
                [1] => 2
                [2] => 10
                [3] => 1
                [4] => 2
                [5] => 1
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => Flash sale
                [1] => 1
                [2] => 9
                [3] => 2
                [4] => 2
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => Discount
                [1] => 1
                [2] => 10
                [3] => 3
            )

    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function group_by($key, $data) {
        $result = array();

        foreach($data as $val) {
            if(array_key_exists($key, $val)){
                $result[$val[$key]][] = $val;
            }else{
                $result[""][] = $val;
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }

    function format_chart($promotions){
        $group_by_date = group_by("date", $promotions);
        $dates = array_keys($group_by_date);
        $top = array_merge(array("date"), $dates);
        $data = array();
        foreach($promotions as $promotion){
            if(isset($data[$promotion['promotion_type']][$promotion['date']])){
                $data[$promotion['promotion_type']][$promotion['date']] += $promotion['goods_num'];
            }
            else{
                $data[$promotion['promotion_type']][$promotion['date']] = $promotion['goods_num'];
            }
        }
        $final[] = $top;
        foreach($data as $key => $val){
            $row[] = $key;
            foreach($dates as $date){
                $count = 0;
                if(isset($val[$date])){
                    $count = $val[$date];
                }
                $row[] = $count;
            }
            $final[] = $row;
            $row = array();
        }
        return $final;
    }

    $formatted_data = format_chart($promotions);
```